# System Monitoring service - Hosted

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a system monitoring service, a bit like [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com/), but for more the system itself than the ruby side of things.

i.e. something like Zabbix, but hosted like New Relic.

I wont something I can just drop an 'agent' on the servers, and then do all the config and monitoring and notifications on a nice slick 3rd party system.

So essential Zabbix Meats New Relic meets Pingdom.

Any ideas?

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Check out scoutapp.com.  It's a hosted monitoring solution that might match what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what you want to monitor you may look at [ip-label](http://www.ip-label.net/)

Answer (score 0):

AlertFox offers good free and paid WEB performance and availability monitoring. In this area it is *much* better than Zabbix, but it lacks the system monitoring features. So it depends what you need :)

http://www.alertfox.com/

Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike, But it's specifically the system level features I need.

Answer (score 0):

I know several places host Silverback http://www.silverbacktech.com/ monitoring.  Or did when we were looking at monitoring solutions a while back.  It looks like they may have been eaten by Dell, and are now Dell Remote Monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

[Monitis](http://portal.monitis.com/) is another option; I've had good experience with them in the past.

Answer (score 0):

[LogicMonitor](http://www.logicmonitor.com/) provides configuration-free hosted monitoring of your network, servers, applications, and storage from one portal.

You don't have to know what needs to be monitored or how to write config scripts - it's all pre-configured for you.

How it works:
• install a single agent on any shared Windows or Linux machine 
• add host names of systems you want monitored
• agent collects data from those systems and sends to LogicMonitor servers in cloud
• alerts are sent via email/sms from LogicMonitor servers (not from agent) to you 
• historical trending graphs show 1 year of data

You can start a free trial and be monitoring all your systems in 30 minutes: http://www.logicmonitor.com/

Answer (score -1):

http://tribily.com is hosted zabbix, pretty much exactly as you describe :)

Comment: product is officially closed